# Karate-Gatling: Callonce does not run

Tags: karate, gatling-plugin

I have a feature file that require login credentials before testing can happen. In Karate, I added a `callonce read(login.feature)` so that the login will only happen once and the credentials can be saved in Karate.

However when I run the same feature file in Karate-Gatling, I run into errors:

```
18:34:58.325 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO  com.intuit.karate - >> lock acquired, begin callonce: read('login.feature')
18:34:58.357 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO  com.intuit.karate - >> lock acquired, begin callonce: read('login.feature')
18:34:58.357 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO  com.intuit.karate - >> lock acquired, begin callonce: read('login.feature')

================================================================================
2019-05-06 18:34:58                                           1s elapsed
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=0      KO=0     )


---- test1 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[##########################################################################]100%
          waiting: 0      / active: 0      / done: 1
================================================================================
```

There is a workaround, where I execute the login.feature first, then feed the login token to the other feature files. However, I was wondering if it is just me, or is the `callonce` (and possibly `call`) function is not supported. I suspect that the Gatling does not wait for the call to return and simply shut the test scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, remember `callonce` is scoped to a feature file.

Use `callSingle()` - you can use it in a feature file (instead of `karate-config.js` where it is normally recommended) - and that is guarateed to lock across all features and run once.